# underscore's some and every functions - susceptible to not short-circuiting?

Tags: javascript, foreach, underscore.js

Are underscore's `some` and `every` functions susceptible to not short-circuiting?

From reading the source, it looks like this can happen if the javascript environment does NOT define the native `some` function but DOES define the native `forEach` method.  Can this happen though?  I guess it's plausible enough but does it ever happen in practice?

Technical nitty gritty backing up my thoughts above:

- `_.some` internally uses `_.forEach` if native `some` is not defined
- `_.forEach` short-circuits early when called from other underscore functions.  It respects a special `breaker` return value.
- This `breaker` object is internal to underscore and cannot be used by non-underscore functions.

I ask this because some people have requested that `breaker` be made available outside underscore so others can get break behavior with `forEach`.  That's been denied because the native `forEach` implementations (which underscore delegates to if available) would not respect this convention and they're striving for consistent behavior.  But it seems `_.some` and `_.every` has the same inconsistency issue, right?

Comment: I think I drank too much, there's a lot I don't seem to understand in this question... :(

Comment: You might want to review the `underscore.js` source, things like `nativeEvery = ArrayProto.every` and `nativeSome = ArrayProto.some` in particular.

Comment: @muistooshort, I've seen those.  Unless I'm nuts they don't answer my question.  I get the feeling my question was poorly asked.  If Array.prototype.forEach is defined but Array.prototype.some is not, we'd have this inconsistency.  Maybe this wouldn't ever happen in a js environment and it would be all or nothing, at least when it comes to these functions?

Comment: The problem is (AFAIK) that `some` could be implemented by Underscore using the native `forEach`, right? Have you read the source to see if this is possible?

Comment: @muistooshort, that's right.  I've read the underscore source.  From that I know the following: `some` is implemented using underscore's `forEach`.  Underscore's `forEach` in turn uses native `forEach` if present.  So far so good.  The rub is, what happens if native `some` is not present so underscore falls back to Native forEach will not break while underscore's will (when used by `some`).

Comment: @muistooshort, scratch last comment.  I didn't get you.

Yep, that's the problem.  I've read the source; this happens if there's NO native `some` but IS a native `forEach`.

So my questions:
1) doesn't that mean `_.some` may be inconsistent with native `some` in that it only sometimes short-circuits?
2) or does this situation never occur?  Maybe no javascript environment would have a native `forEach` but NOT a native `some` defined??  It's certainly plausible but maybe doesn't happen in practice?

I ask because the inconsistency w/ native is why they rejected exposing the `breaker` variable.

Comment: Ditch Underscore and use Lo-Dash instead. Then you'll never have this problem.